# Как нормализовать данную строчку?

Tags: python

Дана функция def normalize_name(s):

Вот пример, как должно быть: "  sir Arthur     Conan   Doyle " normalized to "Sir Arthur Conan Doyle"

1. имя должно начинаться с титула , потом идёт имя, отчество, и фамилия
2. удалить лишние пробелы
3. честь должна быть написана с большой буквы.

Что тут не так?

```
def normalize_name(s):
   'sir Arthur Conan Doyle ".strip().title()'
   'Sir Arthur Conan Doyle'
```

Comment: Какой результат ваша функция возвращает? Нет return

Answer (score 3):

```py
def normalize_name(s):
   c = s.strip().title()
   return c

z = normalize_name('sir Arthur Conan Doyle ')
print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

В случае, если между словами более 1 пробела

```
def normalize_name(s):
     splitted_str = s.split()
     splitted_str[0] = splitted_str[0].capitalize()
     return " ".join(splitted_str)


print(normalize_name("sir    Arthur Conan  Doyle"))
```

Comment: Во-первых вы в конце забыли скобку )